# Does using narrow keywords increase conversion rate?

Tags: marketing, sales

I am going to advertise my book with AdWords.

Does using narrow keywords increase conversion rate?

It seems that no, because conversion rate depends only on clicks, and clicks happen after keywords were already taken into consideration; so it seems not to depend on keywords. But I am not sure whether this my reasoning is correct.

Comment: While marketing questions have been decided by the community to be on topic, I still think that we are not marketing experts and you will get better answers in a SEO community.

Answer (score 1):

By "narrow keywords" do you mean long tail keywords or highly niche-specific keywords?

Long tail keywords are much more descriptive/qualified (think "shoes" versus "red satin dancing shoes for children") and as such may target leads further along the sales funnel. A study published in Search Engine Watch did find long tail keywords to be associated with [higher conversion rates](http://searchenginewatch.com/sew/study/2214529/head-vs-long-tail-keywords-analyzed-impressions-clicks-conversions-profitability).

I suspect niche-specific keywords also hold similar benefits (highly targeted, possibly highly motivated leads) but I haven't personally come across any study citing these. In my own experience with PPC campaigns, the advantages of highly niche-specific keywords need to be balanced with the disadvantages of fewer queries, fewer impressions and less traffic in total.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between long tail keywords and highly niche-specific keywords.

Comment: Well, let's see...think of it as the difference between "graphics utilities for gaming computers" versus "graphics utilities for retrogaming computers". Same number of words, equally detailed search query but the keyword "retrogaming" is very niche-specific and the people searching for it will likely not be interested in the same types of graphics utilities as the other group. This holds true even for shorter search terms using such a niche-specific keyword: "retrogaming graphics" vs "gaming graphics". Searchers use of that keyword in itself is a qualifier.

Comment: Certainly click-through-rate is greater for narrow keywords, as you described. But my question is not about click-through-rate but about conversion-rate. You answered not that question which I've asked

Comment: The link I posted in my original answer referred to a study of conversion rates, which were found to be higher.

Comment: Somewhat tangentially to your question about the association between keywords and conversion rates (answered above), in my own opinion/observation, while conversion is not of course solely dependent on keyword, people who have a clear idea of what they want are more likely to be further along the sales funnel/ready to take action than people who aren't. If your ad/SERP listing convincingly promises to provide them this, it will have a higher click-through; if your landing page delivers on that promise (or at least turns it into belief), you will also see a higher conversion rate.